# MySQL restructure Union All query so it only hits the database once

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT project_id,
'FP' as Phase,
OriginalCommitments,
ApprovedCommitmentChanges,
OriginalCommitments+ApprovedCommitmentChanges as CurrentAssigned,

(SELECT 
sum(ProjectCostBudget.PendingChangeOrders) as PendingScopeChanges
FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 
project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id
where
ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "020.0000.000") as             
PendingScopeChanges,

sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + 
sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete) as EAC,
(sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) +     
sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete)/ 
(sum(ProjectCostBudget.OriginalContractPrice + 
ProjectCostBudget.RegisteredChangeOrders))) as PercentComplete

FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project

inner join ImportCost on ImportCost.ProjectID = project.pmis
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 
project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id

where ImportCost.ProjectID = 'RLCY-BB-01' 
and ImportCost.Task = "020.0000.000"
and ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "020.0000.000"
and ProjectCost.MonthYear != '' 
and ProjectCost.MonthYear like 'July%2018'

Union all

SELECT project_id,
 'D' as Phase,
 OriginalCommitments,
 ApprovedCommitmentChanges,
 OriginalCommitments+ApprovedCommitmentChanges as CurrentAssigned,

 (SELECT 
sum(ProjectCostBudget.PendingChangeOrders) as PendingScopeChanges
FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id
where
ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "030.0000.000") as PendingScopeChanges,

 sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete) as EAC,
 (sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete)/(sum(ProjectCostBudget.OriginalContractPrice + ProjectCostBudget.RegisteredChangeOrders))) as PercentComplete

FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project

inner join ImportCost on ImportCost.ProjectID = project.pmis
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id

where ImportCost.ProjectID = 'RLCY-BB-01' 
and ImportCost.Task = "030.0000.000"
and ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "030.0000.000"
and ProjectCost.MonthYear != '' 
and ProjectCost.MonthYear like 'July%2018'

Union all

SELECT project_id,
 'CP' as Phase,
 OriginalCommitments,
 ApprovedCommitmentChanges,
 OriginalCommitments+ApprovedCommitmentChanges as CurrentAssigned,

 (SELECT 
sum(ProjectCostBudget.PendingChangeOrders) as PendingScopeChanges
FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id
where
ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "040.0000.000") as PendingScopeChanges,

 sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete) as EAC,
 (sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete)/(sum(ProjectCostBudget.OriginalContractPrice + ProjectCostBudget.RegisteredChangeOrders))) as PercentComplete

FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project

inner join ImportCost on ImportCost.ProjectID = project.pmis
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id

where ImportCost.ProjectID = 'RLCY-BB-01' 
and ImportCost.Task = "040.0000.000"
and ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "040.0000.000"
and ProjectCost.MonthYear != '' 
and ProjectCost.MonthYear like 'July%2018'

Union all

SELECT project_id,
 'C' as Phase,
 OriginalCommitments,
 ApprovedCommitmentChanges,
 OriginalCommitments+ApprovedCommitmentChanges as CurrentAssigned,

 (SELECT 
sum(ProjectCostBudget.PendingChangeOrders) as PendingScopeChanges
FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id
where
ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "050.0000.000") as PendingScopeChanges,

 sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete) as EAC,
 (sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete)/(sum(ProjectCostBudget.OriginalContractPrice + ProjectCostBudget.RegisteredChangeOrders))) as PercentComplete

FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project

inner join ImportCost on ImportCost.ProjectID = project.pmis
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id

where ImportCost.ProjectID = 'RLCY-BB-01' 
and ImportCost.Task = "050.0000.000"
and ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "050.0000.000"
and ProjectCost.MonthYear != '' 
and ProjectCost.MonthYear like 'July%2018'

Union all

SELECT project_id,
 'CO' as Phase,
 OriginalCommitments,
 ApprovedCommitmentChanges,
 OriginalCommitments+ApprovedCommitmentChanges as CurrentAssigned,

 (SELECT 
sum(ProjectCostBudget.PendingChangeOrders) as PendingScopeChanges
FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id
where
ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "060.0000.000") as PendingScopeChanges,

 sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete) as EAC,
 (sum(ProjectCost.CurrentWorkCompleted) + sum(ProjectCost.EstimateToComplete)/(sum(ProjectCostBudget.OriginalContractPrice + ProjectCostBudget.RegisteredChangeOrders))) as PercentComplete

FROM `RCLY-DEV`.project

inner join ImportCost on ImportCost.ProjectID = project.pmis
inner join ProjectCostBudget on ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = project.project_id
inner join ProjectCost on ProjectCost.ProjectID = project.project_id

where ImportCost.ProjectID = 'RLCY-BB-01' 
and ImportCost.Task = "060.0000.000"
and ProjectCostBudget.ProjectID = 2 
and ProjectCostBudget.ServiceNumber = "060.0000.000"
and ProjectCost.MonthYear != '' 
and ProjectCost.MonthYear like 'July%2018'
```

But was told this was unacceptable because it makes too many hits to the database and the developer wants a query that just hits the database once. Since the only thing that changes are the where conditions, I tried to just combine them using OR but that seems to both screw up calculations in the nested query and does not return a table with 5 rows. I posted earlier yesterday trying to turn it into a stored procedure that loops through and executes one query 5 times and inserts those records into a temporary table, but was unable to figure that out. Kinda at a loss here and would appreciate any guidance

Comment: Curious, what was the result of this suitable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101806/1422451) to join on a temp table of params from your last post?

Comment: @Parfait It returned no records.

Comment: The values in the poster's temp table should just be adjusted to fit your needs: *ImpCostID* = 'RLCY-BB-01', *PCBID* = 2, *MonthYear* = 'July%2018' for all 5 rows and different *ImpCostTask* AND *PCBServNum* for each row ("020.0000.000", "030.0000.000", "040.0000.000", "050.0000.000", "060.0000.000").

Comment: @Parfait right, I updated them before I tried to run it and it still produced 0 results. Even when i only included one row in the temp table with criteria it still produced nothing.

Comment: Yep, running it in a stored proc but even if i take it out it still gives the same thing, no results. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on

Comment: Can you [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or add a GitHub gist of your attempt? It must be implementation. The other post had a slightly different query. By the way I am assuming you attempted on this query not other one.

Comment: let me try to get something on github for you. the query im trying to run has the pending scope changes subquery completely commented out so it really should just be selecting a few fields and a few aggregates.

Comment: @Parfait this is exactly what im running https://pastebin.com/NDqpV6cB

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY`? I don't see it here. Try removing it. Other debugging steps: 1) remove the qp `ON` clauses one by one and see if results emerge to see which is the problematic clause; 2) run first `SELECT ` of your `UNION` with hard-coded values and see if results emerge (something could have changed in your environment).

Comment: I've tried all that, but it just returns nothing each time.

Comment: Oh! So your actual UNION query (first `SELECT`) returns nothing? Then your attempt is correct. This is a data issue not query code issue.

Comment: Turn your `Query` into an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` string. You will have to replace single quotes inside the string with quad quotes (`''''`). So each of your string values inside the `Query string` will become `... '''' + '{value}' + '''' ...`. Call 'sp_executesql' on your `Query string` variable. Now you are only requesting data 'once' from the database.